# How to properly add a CDN to a Meteor 1.5 project?

Tags: meteor

I have this in `/client/main.html`

```
<head>
  <title>Meteor ESP8266</title>
  <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

The CDN for `bootstrap-toggle.min.js` gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` because the CDN's javascript is loaded before Meteor's built-in jQuery has loaded.

What's the proper way to add JS from CDNs in Meteor 1.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `defer` attribute into your `<script>` tag:

```js
<script defer src="..."></script>
```

That will cause browsers to execute script after the document has been parsed (and other scripts have been loaded).

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).